# Mysterious crashes in Google Play Core lib when using in-app reviews? (wrong line numbers, wrong file names...)

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have a mysterious bug in google play library after implementing in-app reviews, and it does not make sense. This is crash report from console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3790)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3830)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3038)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1971)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1913)
  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting (IPackageManager.java:5720)
  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting (ApplicationPackageManager.java:2912)
  at com.google.android.play.core.internal.bh.h (bh.java:80)
  at com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity.a (PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity.java:16)
  at com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory.create (ReviewManagerFactory.java)
  at com.myapp.mypackage.SettingsActivity.onResume (SettingsActivity.java:11)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume (Instrumentation.java:1361)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:7415)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3765)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3830)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3038)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Problems:

1. There is no class named `com.google.android.play.core.internal.bh.h`. Why it wasnt deobfuscated? I uploaded correct mapping.txt file
2. It says crash happened at line 11 in method `onResume` in my class `com.myapp.mypackage.SettingsActivity.onResume`. That is incorrect, on line 11 there is no code, just imports...`onResume` method in my activity is somewhere on 100+ line. Why crash report reports random, incorrect lines?
3. I tried to also investigate class `com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity.a (PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity.java:16)` but once again - there is nothing on line 16, only imports

My code (practically just a copy paste from official Google Docs) - it apparently crashes somewhere here, but I do not know on what line and why crash happens, since there is incorrect line numbers in crash report:

```
ReviewManagerFactory reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context);
Task<ReviewInfo> request = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow();
            request.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ReviewInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ReviewInfo> task) {
                    // 1. everything ok => we show in-app review sheet at the bottom
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // We can get the ReviewInfo object
                        ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
                        Task<Void> flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow((Activity) context, reviewInfo);
                        flow.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                            // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                            // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                            // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
                        }).addOnFailureListener(task2 -> {
                            // nothing
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

How to actually solve crash reports like this, when classes names or lines do not make any sense?

Do I have to add some lines in proguard?

Ay tops, hints or advices how to deal with crash reports like this? Thanks

Comment: Hi @qkx. I have the same problem with ReviewManagerFactory. I tried wrap this in try-catch block, but it does not work. I think we should report the problem to the developers of the Play Core library. But I do not know where it can be done